# Using Sapper preload to fetch image

Tags: javascript, image, svelte, preload, sapper

I would like to use Sapper's `preload` function to preload a large hero image that appears in the viewport of the home page of my site. I have tried the following in the component that houses this image:

```
<script context="module">

    const imageUrl = "/images/hero.jpg";

    export async function preload(page, session) {
        const res = await this.fetch(imageUrl);
        const preloadedImage = await res.blob();
        return {preloadedImage};
    }

</script>

<script>
    let preloadedImage;
    let heroImage=URL.createObjectURL(preloadedImage);
</script>

<img src={heroImage} alt="heroes" />
```

The console error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

at `service-worker.js:1`

Is it possible to preload an image using Sapper `preload` and if so, what it the correct way? FYI, I did try using`<link href="images/hero.jpg" rel="preload" as="image">` in the HTML header before trying Sapper's `preload` function, but the image still loads as the page is visible.

Comment: I don't think preloading an image in a page which is loading makes any sense. With preloading you would delayed the initial page load and make the user wait longer before anything shows up in the browser. What you could do is to base64 encode the image and  insert it into html as a text. Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813726/load-images-before-loading-any-html-element

Comment: In general I agree, @Molda. This is a niche case. The site is a low traffic personal portfolio site with a limited intended audience. The main content above the fold on the home page is a high-quality jpg. In this specific case, I don't mind a delay in page load time as a trade-off for an image that appears intact along with the rest of the page, without progressive loading or a placeholder image. I also would like the image to be cached so that it loads quickly from the browser cache once downloaded.